# Multiple conditions in rewrite rule in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a rewrite rule in my asp.net mvc app in config file:

```
<rule name="Website1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?website1.com" />
      <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/website1/" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="\website1\{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

How does the rule work in this situation with two conditions? Both condition must be true?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, both conditions must be true.

> [Rule Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Rule_conditions)
>
> Conditions are defined within a  collection of a rewrite
>   rule. This collection has an attribute called logicalGrouping that
>   controls how conditions are evaluated. If a rule has conditions, then
>   the rule action will be performed only if rule pattern is matched and:
>
> - All conditions were evaluated to true, provided that
>     `logicalGrouping="MatchAll"` was used.
> - At least one of the conditions
>     was evaluated to true, provided that `logicalGrouping="MatchAny"` was
>     used.

The Doc is not very clear about which logical grouping is to be used by default but I can say that it is `MatchAll`.

In other words, `<conditions>` is the same as `<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">`.